# Express js if logic dosn't work it always return the same message

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

when I execute this code it always returns the same message even if  i send different email

```
  let message = "";
  const findQuery = "select email from Users where email = ?";
  const queryResult = await db.query(findQuery, [req.body.email]);
  if(queryResult[0] === req.body.email){
    message = "Welcome Back"
  }else if (queryResult[0] != req.body.email) {
    message = "No Access"
  }
  res.send(message);
```

i expect deffrent message

Comment: Have you logged `queryResult[0]` and `req.body.email`? Which message is being returned? Could `queryResult[0]` require the column name too?

Comment: @mykaf I logged the object it returns an array with an object containing the email as a value

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the same lookup twice.

Here you are fetching all the emails that match `req.body.email`:

```
const findQuery = "select email from Users where email = ?";
const queryResult = await db.query(findQuery, [req.body.email]);
```

If queryResults isn't empty, it should always equal `req.body.email`. Therefore this if-selection is redundant.

```
if (queryResult[0] === req.body.email) {
  message = "Welcome Back";
} else if (queryResult[0] != req.body.email) {
  message = "No Access";
}
```

I think what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
const [email] = await db.query(findQuery, [req.body.email]).catch(err => {
  throw err;
});

if (email && email.length > 0) {
  message = "Welcome Back";
} else {
  message = "No Access";
}
```

Comment: still the same thing happen

Comment: Could you perhaps explain a bit more regarding the problem? What message are you getting? What message were you expecting?

Comment: https://tmpfiles.org/dl/197263/simplescreenrecorder---_...mp4

Comment: here is the entire code for the project https://shrib.com/?v=co#Lyla_7pb52q

Comment: Could you perhaps `console.log(queryResult)` and check the value

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a catch and a little bit more syntactic sugar. Could you try that?

Comment: still the same i think it has somthing to do with truthy of falsey

Comment: i fixed i just add [0]                                                                                              if(email[0]){
    message = "Welcome Back"
  }else {
    message = "Need To Rgister";
  }

Answer (score 0):

i fix it its about truthy or falsy in js i add [0] and its work beacuse if you think about if you enter non-existing email and logged in the console that's what you will get [{}] an empty object and that empty object is truthy and thats the reason why it return the same answer
notice the object destruction we make to take the specific row

```
const findQuery = "select email from Users where email = ?";
const [email] = await db.query(findQuery, [req.body.email]);
if(email[0]){
  res.send(email[0].email);
}else {
 res.send("Need To Register");
}
```